# Directing a live domain to a virtual machine via hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, virtual-machines

Here's the goal:

I want www.foo.com, which exists in the wild and is currently redirecting to www.foobar.com in the wild, to resolve to my vm site.  The VM version of this site is a *complete rebuild* so no redirects in the wild are being applied to foo.com locally.

I'm working on foo.com locally in a vm with apache2 running. The IP of the VM is 192.168.207.128 and everything is installed in the VM correctly as far as I can tell.

The problem is when I go to www.foo.com, i get redirected to www.foobar.com production site, not my foo.com vm site. when I go to www.foo.com/some-test-page, it goes to the VM.

My hosts file entry in windows looks like this:

```
192.168.207.128     www.foo.com
```

My hosts entry on the VM is obviously correct because foo.com/test is resolving. I can ping foo.com from my windows box and it response/resolves to the right ip just fine. Insights as to what I missed? I have this sinking feeling its something stupid...

Thanks!

Comment: Clear your browser cache and then restart the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly your browser cached the redirection? try clearing your browser's cache

Comment: mercy.  I KNEW it was something stupid!  Thank you both so much.  Michael, I'd plus you if I could since you're both right.

Comment: plussed him for you:)